# Qt Group menu actions together

Tags: c++, qt

I have some `QMenu` objects that share some `QAction`'s between them and toolbars.

The detail here is that I want to reproduce some menu parts over other menus. For instance, in my `QMainWindow` object's MenuBar, I have something like

```
File
  (x) New
  (x) Open
  (x) Save
  (x) ------
  (x) Add Sketch...
  (-) Export...
  (-) Import...
```

And then, in some context menu, I want to reproduce the same exact structure with only the actions marked with `(x)` , using the same action objects. I want to do this over several menus.

The naive approach is to repeat the same code when building the `QMainWindow` menu and the context menu that repeats the structure. But this means repeating code and therefore doubling the maintenance effort (times the number of repeated menu actions).

Is there a direct approach of solving this on Qt?

Comment: why don't you create a class Menu which have all these actions as variables and connect it to a window send in the constructor ? then add the 2 (-) action to the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

One option can be to have the actions stored in a dictionary, and then save different lists of keys for each submenu. All you have to do later is just to build the menu using a simple for. A draft code may look like:

```
QMap<QString, QAction*> actions;
actions["new"] = new QAction(...); // connect, etc.
actions["-"] = new QAction(...); // for separator

QMap<QString, QStringList> menus;
menus["file"] << "new" << "save" << ... << "import" << ...;
menus["context1"] << "new" << "save" << ...;

QMenu* buildMenu(const QString& name) {
  if (!menus.contains(name)) return nullptr;
  auto menu = new QMenu();
  Q_FOREACH (const auto& entry, menus[name]) {
    menu->addAction(actions[entry]);
  }
  return menu;
}
```

Finally, make `actions` and `menus` available to `buildMenu` (a class, anonymous namespace together some initialisation...). Also remember to delete the returned menu after using it.